# The ratio between $m_W$ and decay distance of hadrons resulting from pp collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, collision, bosons

A pp collision results in:

$pp\rightarrow t\overline{t}\\
t \rightarrow bW^{+}\\
\overline{t} \rightarrow \overline{b}W^{-}\\
W^{+}\rightarrow u\overline{d}\\
W^{-}\rightarrow\overline{u}d$

From b we get $B^{+}$ or $B^{-}$

I have to calculate how much the decay distance of $B^{\pm}$ changes if I double W boson's mass.

So here is how I thought of doing it: I know that the amplitude of the t\ $\overline{t}$ collision is proportional to $\frac{1}{q^2-m_W^2}$ where q is the virtual particle and $m_W$ is W boson's mass. I've shown that $q^2 \ll m_W$. So that means that the amplitude is $\propto\frac{1}{m_W^2}$. We know that the decay rate is proportional to the squared amplitude, that is $\Gamma \propto \frac{1}{m_W^4}$.

So I thought that since the decay rate is inversely prorportial to the mean life time of particle's decay, then perhaps $\Gamma \propto \tau \propto$ distance, hence $\propto m_W^4$.

But then, on the other hand, we know that the weak interaction's range is proportional to $\frac{1}{m_W}$. So I am at a loss here.